# Replace all unmatched surrogate pairs with replacement character in JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-16, surrogate-pairs

I have a JavaScript string that I'm writing to a file. I need to replace any unmatched surrogate pairs with the replacement character. Is there some regex character class that only matches unpaired surrogates or do I have to do some additional processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String.prototype.toWellFormed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toWellFormed) replaces any *lone surrogates* with the Unicode replacement character U+FFFD `�`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function toWellFormed(s) {
  return s.replace(/\p{Surrogate}/gu, '\uFFFD')
}
```

```js
toWellFormed('foo ')                  // 'foo '
toWellFormed('foo \uD834\uDF06')       // 'foo '
toWellFormed('foo \uD834')             // 'foo �'
toWellFormed('foo \uDF06\uDF06\uDF06') // 'foo ���'
```